# lxml: XMLSyntaxError: Unsupported version '2.0'

Tags: python, lxml

`lxml` fails with an exception, when using XML version 2.0.

Test:

```
class TestLXML(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_lxml(self):
        from lxml import etree

        etree.fromstring('<?xml version="2.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><test>test</test>')
```

Result:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/viator/coding/esb/mdmesb/packages/smev/core/request/test.py", line 33, in test_lxml
    etree.fromstring('<?xml version="2.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><test>test</test>')
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3032, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:68121)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1786, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:102470)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1674, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:101299)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1074, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:96481)
  File "parser.pxi", line 582, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91290)
  File "parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:92476)
  File "parser.pxi", line 622, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91772)
XMLSyntaxError: Unsupported version '2.0', line 1, column 19
```

Does lxml not support version 2.0? What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like there is no formal specification for a XML 2.0 - just a W3C working group informative specification, which explicitly says "The XML Security Working Group has agreed not to progress this Canonical XML 2.0 specification further as a Recommendation" . (https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n2/). Further write ups on "XML 2.0" on Wikpedia and Stackoverflow corroborate this.

So, due to the non existence of a formal specification, there is no way a production-quality, formal, strict checking library as lxml can read it.

If your documents are XML 1.1 compatible, jsut replace the initial "2.0" on the document by "1.1" - treating the XML as a string, prior to parsing it. If they are not, you will have to pick up another library which works with the informative W3C spec (or craft your own).

Some googling finds out there is no such a thing like "XML 2.0" supported in Python by any libraries. Another option is to document which features you need from XML 2.0, if any, and create a XML pre-processor to handle those.